# Getting the value of an object that is named like an array

Tags: postman

I'm trying to write a test script in Postman that should verify that a specific object has some value. However, the object is named like an array and I'm not able to access it. Here is the response body that I receive:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "[0].EntityType": [
            "'Entity Type' has a range of values which does not include '2'.",
            "Entity Type must be in enum values"
        ]
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to access the data within this "[0].EntityType" object like:

```
pm.test("Entity Type must be in enum", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(jsonData.errors.[0].EntityType[1]).to.eql("Entity Type must be in enum values");
});
```

And as you can guess, it's not working. Do you have guys have any ideas on how I should handle this?

I tried to work around this by creating a new variable with a normal naming (let's say "errorType") and I give it the value of the actual object ([0].EntityType[1]) and changing it in the assertion (like jsonData.errors.errorType). It didn't work. I also tried to put the object in quotes like jsonData.errors.**"[0].EntityType[1]"** but this doesn't do the magic as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
pm.expect(jsonData.errors.[0].EntityType[1]).to.eql("Entity Type must be in enum values");
```

with

```
pm.expect(jsonData.errors["[0].EntityType"][1]).to.eql("Entity Type must be in enum values");
```